# On Jacobi theta functions and some curious evaluations

Tags: special-functions, radicals, closed-form, theta-functions

(*This post has been modified to include* $\vartheta_2$.) The *Jacobi theta functions* are well-known for the identity,

$$\vartheta_2^4 - \vartheta_3^4 +\vartheta_4^4 = 0 $$

so this post will involve ***4th*** roots, and will focus on the first two functions. To recall,

$$\vartheta_2(q) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{(n+1/2)^2},\quad\quad
\vartheta_3(q) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}$$

with the ***nome*** $q = e^{\pi i\tau}$. In [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Lemniscatic_values), we find some curious identities which inspired this post. Let $\color{red}{\tau = \sqrt{-1}}$, then we have the complementary pairs:

---

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(q^4)}{\vartheta_2(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{1+\sqrt[4]4-\sqrt[4]{32}}{4}\\
\sqrt[4]4\,\left(\frac{\vartheta_3(q^4)}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{1+\sqrt[4]4+\sqrt[4]{32}}{4}\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(q^6)}{\vartheta_2(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{\sqrt[4]3-\sqrt[4]9-\sqrt[4]{12}+\sqrt[4]{27}}{6}\\
\sqrt[4]4\,\left(\frac{\vartheta_3(q^6)}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{\sqrt[4]3+\sqrt[4]9+\sqrt[4]{12}+\sqrt[4]{27}}{6}\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(q^{10})}{\vartheta_2(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{-3+\sqrt[4]{64}-\sqrt[4]{80}+\sqrt[4]{100}}{10}\\
\sqrt[4]4\,\left(\frac{\vartheta_3(q^{10})}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{3+\sqrt[4]{64}+\sqrt[4]{80}+\sqrt[4]{100}}{10}\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(q^{12})}{\vartheta_2(q)}\right)^2 &=\frac{\sqrt[4]3-\sqrt[4]6+\sqrt[4]9+\sqrt[4]{12}+\sqrt[4]{27}-\sqrt[4]{54}-\sqrt[4]{72}}{12}\\
\sqrt[4]4\,\left(\frac{\vartheta_3(q^{12})}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^2 &=\frac{\sqrt[4]3+\sqrt[4]6+\sqrt[4]9+\sqrt[4]{12}+\sqrt[4]{27}+\sqrt[4]{54}+\sqrt[4]{72}}{12}\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(q^{20})}{\vartheta_2(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{3-\sqrt[4]{10}-\sqrt[4]{50}+\sqrt[4]{64}+\sqrt[4]{80}+\sqrt[4]{100}-\sqrt[4]{162}-\sqrt[4]{250}}{20}\\
\sqrt[4]4\,\left(\frac{\vartheta_3(q^{20})}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^2 &= \frac{3+\sqrt[4]{10}+\sqrt[4]{50}+\sqrt[4]{64}+\sqrt[4]{80}+\sqrt[4]{100}+\sqrt[4]{162}+\sqrt[4]{250}}{20}\end{align}$$

---

Nicely symmetric, aren't they? It is apparent that for positive integer $n$, then it will be a radical. But there are obvious questions.

**Question 1:** Why (for certain $n$) can the pair be expressed as a sum of $4$th roots of ***integers***?

$$n\,\left(\frac{\vartheta_2(q^{n})}{\vartheta_2(q)}\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \large{\pm\sqrt[4]{x_i}}$$

$$n\,\sqrt[4]4\,\left(\frac{\vartheta_3(q^{n})}{\vartheta_3(q)}\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \large{\sqrt[4]{x_i}}$$

**Question 2:** Are there infinite $n$ such this is the case? If so, what is the next $n$? (My guess is $n = 24$.)

Comment: @Vladimir Reshetnikov Care to find the next $n$?

Comment: This looks rather very peculiar. The ratios of eta functions in your post are algebraic numbers, but to express them using 4th roots is new to me.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I know, right? To be candid, the ones $n<20$ are not mine, but I've done a lot of work on algebraic numbers, and to express "natural" theta ratios as sums of 4th roots of ***integers*** (divided by a common denominator) needs some explanation.

Comment: What I noticed above is that the integers under root sign have prime factors which are also factors of $n$. That has probably something to do with the values of elliptic modulus $l$ corresponding to nome $q^n$.

Comment: Morally 4th roots aren't too much surprising, the lattices $\Bbb{Z}+k\frac{27 i}2 \Bbb{Z}$ have CM by (an order of) $\Bbb{Q}(i)$, your algebraic numbers are abelian over $\Bbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: @reuns Hi reuns, long time no see. The minimal polynomials, as expected, have degrees that is a power of 2. However, a solvable eqn with deg that is $2^n$ is not general reducible to this form. Im checking other theta ratios and eta ratios.

Comment: @reuns I've added $\vartheta_2(q)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I've added $\vartheta_2(q)$, and the forms are nicely complementary to $\vartheta_3(q)$. Unfortunately, $\vartheta_4(q)$ resists being put in the same form.

Comment: $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(i,V_3(q^n)))/\Bbb{Q}(i))$ is a quotient of $Cl(\Bbb{Z}[4 n i])$. Probably need to understand how $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(i,\{ p^{1/4}, p \text{ prime}\})/\Bbb{Q}(i))$ embeds as a quotient of the idele class group of $\Bbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: @reuns In your opinion, are there are infinite $n$ such that the ratio can be put in this form? For some reason, I'm suspecting $n = 2^m p$ where $p$ is a Fermat prime. Just a guess.